# get new id from new attribute option

Tags: magento2, attributes

I am creating a product programaticlly, and sometimes I need to add a new option to some product attribute. 
For adding the new option my code is:

```
$option = array();
$option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
$option['value']['$attributeValue'][0] = $attributeValue;

$eavSetup = $eavSetupFactory->create();
$eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
```

If I do a

```
$attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($attributeValue);
```

to get the new optionId, nothing is returning, and then I can not add this attribute value to my new product.

If I go to backend the new attribute is being created.

Do anyone knows how can I get the Id from my new created attribute option?

Comment: Which is your `$attribute` class?

Comment: the class is \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface